# Вывод истории посещений на сайте 1с битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день! Подскажите, как можно на сайте 1С Битрикс вывести историю, где   указываются все даты авторизаций зарегистрированного пользователя. LAST_LOGIN не подходит, т.к. он выводит только дату последней авторизации.

Answer (score 1):

В административном разделе есть "Журнал событий" , `Настройки->Инструменты->Журнал событий`. Если хотите где-то в публичной части выводить, то через API обращайтесь к нему и выводите.

Comment: Пробовала так делать, но он выводится только для администратора, если из под  зарегистрированного пользователя зайти, то на странице пишет "Доступ запрещен", как дать доступ в настройках групп пользователей и в самом "Журнале событий"  не могу найти.

Comment: Для публичной части существует аналогичный [компонент](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/settings/settings/components_2/event_list.php). Отображайте и настраивайте шаблон вывода так как Вам нужно. Шаблон находится в `Компоненты`->`Служебные`.

Comment: Я разместила bitrix:event_list на странице, но опять же для администратора изменения показываются, для зарегистрированного пользователя ничего не выводится.

Comment: вы должны настроить доступ для группы пользователей, чтобы они могли просматривать. необязательно это должна быть группа администраторов. нужно определить группу пользователей и дать ей права на чтение в настройках доступа к главному модулю. но не забудьте ограничить в шаблоне вывод информации, чтобы пользователь видел только свою историю.

Comment: Заметила, то что "Журнал изменений" показывает только историю изменений на сайте и не выводит дату авторизации пользователя (и через настройки никак это не поправить)